# pion/webrtc - How do I set audio sink and source in GO Pion API?

Tags: go, terminal, webrtc, janus-gateway

I'm working on a CLI Go app to run in the background on my Linux server. This is an implementation of [pion/webrtc](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/). My Go app is connecting to the Janus, but not receiving or sending audio. I need to send microphone audio and receive audio from Janus. I guess that I should link my audio sink/source in pion, but I'm confused.

I'm not sure about this code:

```
// Create a audio track
opusTrack, err := webrtc.NewTrackLocalStaticSample(webrtc.RTPCodecCapability{MimeType: "audio/opus"}, "audio", "pion")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else if _, err = peerConnection.AddTrack(opusTrack); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Neither this:

```
    gst.CreatePipeline("opus", []*webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample{opusTrack}, "audiotestsrc").Start()
```

I used the sample code of [pion/example-webrtc-applications/janus-gateway](https://github.com/pion/example-webrtc-applications/tree/master/janus-gateway).

My whole code [here](https://github.com/moigamijunior/webrtc-go/blob/main/client/main.go).

Thanks for helping!

Comment: the first adds track t the peer offer. The second pipes the actual audio / video stream to the net. Read the comments ?

Comment: @mh-cbon I know what those lines do. What I don't know is if they are complete. I don't know why I can't receive and send audio. This is connecting to Janus, but not sending data or receiving. Do you have a clue?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
    gst.CreatePipeline("opus", []*webrtc.TrackLocalStaticSample{opusTrack}, "autoaudiosrc").Start()
```

"autoaudiosrc" is the matter.

Linux Ubuntu Server 21.04.4